# Integration inside and outside of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

```
EQU = {Y'[s] == -2 X[s] /Sin[ 2 Y[s]] Z[s], 
   X'[s] == Sin[X[s]] Cos[Y[s]]/3, Z'[s] == Cos[Y[s]] Cos[X[s]], 
   X[0] == 0, Y[0] == .3, Z[0] == 1, V1'[s] == Z[s]^2 Cos[Y[s]], 
   V1[0] == 0};
NDSolve[EQU, {X, Y, Z, V1}, {s, 0, 2}];
{x[u_], y[u_], z[u_], v1[u_]} = {X[u], Y[u], Z[u], V1[u]} /. First[%];
Plot[{x[s], y[s], z[s], v1[s]}, {s, 0, 2}, PlotLabel -> "Z X Y V1"]
v2[s_] = NIntegrate[z[s]^2 Cos[y[s]], {s, 0, 2}];
Plot[{x[s], y[s], z[s], v2[s]}, {s, 0, 2}, PlotLabel -> "Z X Y v2"]
```

EDIT1:

V1 is calculated inside NDSolve correctly but the same function (forgotten in the first instance) is calculated with a different name V2 outside NDSolve separately. I used earlier obtained function definitions for constituents as input in NIntegrate. But it does not work. There is something I miss in V2 ( where V1 calculated correctly from initial point of differential equation solution, but fails for V2.) Please help to find it out.

EDIT2

```
r1 = 3.25; ro = 1; lmax = 5;
EQN := {ph1'[
     l] == -Cos[ph1[l]]/
      rr1[l]*(2 rr1[l]^2 - 3 ro^2)/(rr1[l]^2 - ro^2), 
   rr1'[l] == Sin[ph1[l]], z1'[l] == Cos[ph1[l]], ph1[0] == 0, 
   zz1[0] == 0, rr1[0] == r1, vol1[l] == Pi rr1[l]^2 Cos[ph1[l]], 
   vol1[0] == 0};
NDSolve[EQN, {ph1, rr1, z1, vol1}, {l, 0, lmax}];
{r[u_], ph[u_], z[u_], 
   vol[u_]} := {rr1[u], ph1[u], z1[u], vol1[u]} /. First[%];
P1 = ParametricPlot[{z[l], r[l]}, {l, 0, lmax}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
ParametricPlot[{z[l], ph[l]}, {l, 0, lmax}, AspectRatio -> 1]
volume[smax_] := NIntegrate[Pi r[l]^2 Cos[ph[l]], {l, 0, smax}]
Plot[{ph[l], volume[l]}, {l, 0, lmax}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

The above does not work, although earlier it was ok.

EDIT3

Error messages before correct results suggested by MMM remedy for EDIT2:

[image]

Comment: Could you be MUCH clearer about what exactly your problem is?

Comment: Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is

```
{Y[s_], Z[s_], V1[s_]} = {Y[s], Z[s], V1[s]} /.First@NDSolve[EQU, {X, Y, Z, V1}, {s, 0, 2}];
V2[y_] := NIntegrate[Z[s]^2 Cos[Y[s]], {s, 0, y}];
Plot[{V1[s], V2[s]}, {s, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Directive[Red, Dashed]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Please avoid using single capital alphabets.

**Response to Edit 2**

`zz1[0]==0` should be `z1[0]==0`. `vol1[l]` should be `vol1'[l]`.

```
r1 = 3.25; ro = 1; lmax = 5;
EQN = {ph1'[l] == -Cos[ph1[l]]/ rr1[l]*(2 rr1[l]^2 - 3 ro^2)/(rr1[l]^2 - ro^2), 
   rr1'[l] == Sin[ph1[l]], z1'[l] == Cos[ph1[l]], ph1[0] == 0, 
   z1[0] == 0, rr1[0] == r1, vol1'[l] == Pi rr1[l]^2 Cos[ph1[l]],vol1[0] == 0};
{rr1[l_], ph1[l_], z1[l_],vol1[l_]} = {rr1[l], ph1[l], z1[l], vol1[l]} /. 
   First[NDSolve[EQN, {ph1, rr1, z1, vol1}, {l, 0, lmax}]];
volme[x_] := NIntegrate[Pi rr1[l]^2 Cos[ph1[l]], {l, 0, x}]
Plot[{vol1[l], volme[l]}, {l, 0, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: It works but with error messages..

Comment: nice answer, note that you can extract the solution functions also like this: `{X, Y, Z, V1} = NDSolveValue[EQU, {X, Y, Z, V1}, {s, 0, 2}]`.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thanks. I saw your two answers. I will try your idea.